# Are these Houthi Rebels in Yemen the same people who ran the Mutawakkilite Kingdom of Yemen?

Tags: middle-east, arabia, ethnicity

I saw on the news that the [area of Houthi control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houthi_takeover_in_Yemen) roughly corresponded to [North Yemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutawakkilite_Kingdom_of_Yemen), which was a kingdom [overthrown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Yemen_Civil_War) with [Nasser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamal_Abdel_Nasser)'s help in 1962. Are these Houthis the same sort of people who were the rulers of the Kingdom of Yemen?

Answer (score 4):

The Mutawakkili kingdom was ruled by the imam of the Zaydi sect. The Houthis are Zaydis, but they are not from the family of the Imams; in this sense they are not “the same lot”, as you put it. It would not be surprising if they would attempt to restore the imamate, but as yet they do not seem to have suggested this.